# tinymce "Link" popup throwing error, not working

Tags: links, tinymce, visual-editor

I am unable to access the new lightbox-style link popup window. When I try to open it, I get an "error on page" message, and the popup doesn't appear. I've tried on ffx, ie & chrome, on a pc and a mac. I go to work and all is well, on all those same browsers, pc & mac. I can't find any pattern.

I've logged out & back in again, cleaned cache, refresh, yada, yada. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how i might fix it?

Comment: Can you give us more information about the error? Install Firebug or use a debug console in your browser and see whether it gives more information. Also, try deactivating all your plugins and switch to the default theme to see if the error disappears. If it does, re-enable your plugins one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? It was a reasonable question...

Comment: Hard to tell (it didn't come from me), but maybe because you did not offer all possible information? Like the full description of the error, and whether you tried to disable plugins and other sources of errors (and as it turned out, it was your extra code that caused it, not WordPress code). But this is very hard for these kind of "troubleshoot" questions, because if you knew what caused it you wouldn't need to ask us :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I added some custom javascript further down the page hat was somehow ruining the tinymce popup js. I wasn't able to figure out exactly what was causing the problem, I needed to comment it out and it works okay now.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and adding the answer. Don't forget that you can accept it too, marking this question as resolved.